# How to share worlds between platforms with Minecraft Better Together

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have read that with the new "Better Together Update" (BTU) it is now possible to [create a world on one platform and then continue playing it on a different platform](https://news.microsoft.com/en-gb/2017/09/22/minecraft-better-together-update-lets-start-console-keep-playing-mobile/).  However, I am having trouble finding details of how this is supposed to work to determine if it would do what I am hoping it would and therefore whether it is worth my time/money.

I have some saved worlds on Minecraft for XBox One, all done in creative mode.  I am able to import them into what is now just called "Minecraft" which as of the BTU is what is being used to mean the cross-platform version.   Can I now play this same world on my Windows 10 PC?   If I go to the Minecraft web site it offers to sell me the "Java Edition" with the addendum "includes edition for Windows 10".   But from what I have read, anything that has the word "edition" in it isn't the cross platform version.   It's very unclear to me what I would actually be buying here.

If it is possible to open the same world on different platforms, exactly how would I go about doing this?  On the XBox I have to sign in with an outlook.com e-mail address to access my worlds, or my kids' sign-ins to access their worlds, is it the same from the PC? And where would my world be saved?   I have read that XBox saves will be in the cloud, but PC saves will be local, so how can I get a cloud save onto my PC?  And then how can I get it back to the cloud when I am done so I can play it on the console again?  Will there be two copies floating around, making it possible for me to make a backup on my PC?

How will this interact with world editors?  At some point will I be able to start a game on XBox, transfer it to the PC, open it in a world editor, make some changes, and then transfer it back to the XBox?

Comment: "Minecraft" refers to the main part of the game that is shared between the devices, everything with "edition" specifies the device. The "Windows 10 edition" is part of the unified Minecraft. To make it all even more confusing, gaming.SE's tags handle it differently and inconsistently.

Comment: The Windows 10 Edition includes a feature for easy export. It can't be viewed on an outside website without being exported. You can download a world from an XBox and then import it into Windows 10 Edition.

Comment: @TheodoreJameson So I've got a world from my XBox One that is saved... presumably in the cloud.  How can I get this world file into my PC so I can look at it?

Comment: @Michael If you are able to download the world as a .mcworld file, when you launch it on your PC it should open Minecraft

Comment: @TheodoreJameson Where do I go to download it?

Comment: @Michael This link should help: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=zLtohPx28Zk

Answer (score 4):

There is a way to transfer worlds from the Xbox to windows 10 and back using [Minecraft Realms](https://minecraft.net/en-us/realms/), but it will cost some money and availability may depend on your country.

You sign up for the Realms service in the game (on either platform) and then the realm appears on the list of worlds you can log into. A pencil button next to the realm name opens the Edit dialog, and that screen has two buttons you will use. First use "Replace World" which allows you to upload a world file from your local gaming platform to the realm. You'll do this on the Xbox, or the one that has the world you're trying to transfer. Then, on the other platform, used the "Download World" button to import the world.

[image: Realm select screen]

[image: Realm edit dialog]

I've just tried this and it works fine, but it does require a subscription to the Minecraft Realm service. I think you can sign up for this service through multiple different stores, like Google Play or the Microsoft Store. Tonight it was $3.99 / month for the "You + 2" monthly subscription, I'm sure that will eventually change.

You can cancel after transferring the world if you want but if you plan to play on both platforms you will probably want to just leave it subscribed, then you don't even have to mess with downloading the realm. You could still download the world as a backup, but the service will also create backups periodically. These appear in the in-game menu and the world can be restored from them, but I'm not sure what schedule they are created on and there doesn't seem to be a way make it take a backup.

[image: Realm Backups screen]

Comment: This works but no longer is a suitable solution because thanks to [this bug](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MCPE-42091) it's not possible to download worlds larger than 500MB (actually a bit less than this).

Answer (score 1):

There is a program called UFO Transfer that can be used to access your MC folder on Xbox one and other devices. To transfer them using a NTFS formatted USB stick, they can be copied to the win10 folder and played, or edited with the universal MC Editor from OprizeLP! I've looked, and the only method anyone talks about is using Realms.

Finally, a real way to transfer free. I ran across this program seeing tutorials on adding Mods (Behavior/texture Packs) to Xbox one.

Comment: This looks like a free program in the microsoft store... could you expand your answer a bit on the steps to take once the program is installed on the XBox One?  For instance, can I use this directly on the XBox, what folder path do I look for the files at, more info about the USB memory stick on the XBox One, etc.

Comment: If you don't mind, I'm going to edit this answer to add more details once I have got it working.

Comment: Well I tried to edit this to expand your answer to fill in the missing details, but for some reason it was rejected.  I guess I just don't understand how this is supposed to work.  I was *trying* to give YOU the credit for the answer, instead of building on your answer to create my own answer.  Guess I'll leave in a huff, instead. *stamps foot*

Comment: Well as of a few months ago this method no longer works although I just discovered that.  It appears that Microsoft has *deliberately* disabled File Explorer (which UFO Transfer relies on to access hidden folders) specifically (according to some people) to prevent the very type of thing I'm trying to do.  Any idea how to get around this?  I'm pretty upset right now as all the worlds I have offloaded to my PC are orphaned there and I can no longer swap my kids' works to my PC and back.

Comment: @Michael If this is no longer working, you should un-accept the answer

Answer (score -1):

So I was reading you guys answers and I didn’t want to delet my saved data so I Radomly went to settings on my switch and and I went to profile and there is a option that says “Clear Account sign in data” so I clicked it and went back to the home screen and it will now let me sign into my account and I still have all my worlds and Resource packs I hope this helps you!!!

Comment: This does not answer the question asked.  Please keep answer on-topic.