# How to transfer Minecraft worlds from/to a Switch for free?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, nintendo-switch

I'd like to transfer MCBE worlds to and from my Nintendo Switch.

I know that one way to do it is using a Realm, as detailed in [this other question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/363493/250180), but I would like to do it *for free*, and sticking with *non-third party methods only* (although I am open to using homebrew).

Which method would be best to transfer my worlds?

Comment: I'm asking about a method that doesn't require a subscription to Realms and Nintendo Switch Online

Comment: I'm not too familiar with how the Switch online services work, but the other post mentioned using a free trial for realms. Is that something you don't want to do/possible anymore? You mentioned "for free" - that should be what you're after then, no? Or do you have to have a Nintendo subscription (like Xbox Live for Xbox) in order to even go this route?

Comment: @TimmyJim Of course for _once_ I could both a Realms and Switch Online trial (the latter is required for basically any official online activity, it seems), but of course I'm looking for a permanently reliable method