# Can I play my Minecraft worlds from my Switch on Pocket Edition?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have a Nintendo Switch Minecraft world with my friends and got Minecraft Pocket Edition to play on the go. I signed in to the same account but there is no sync old worlds button on the mobile app. I couldn't find how to do it anywhere online either. Does anyone know how to transfer Switch worlds to PE or tell me if it's even possible, please?

Comment: You got PE to play on the go? You do know that Switches are portable, right?

Comment: I know but carrying a switch everywhere is impracticle for me.

Comment: related and possibly a duplicate of https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/321635/224120

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to share worlds between platforms with Minecraft Better Together](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/321635/how-to-share-worlds-between-platforms-with-minecraft-better-together)